# Trouble with dependencies in Android project within Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

After upgrading the capacitor version of my project to `5.0.5` I've got two problems with the `InternalUtils.Java` Class:

```
public static PackageInfo getPackageInfo(PackageManager pm, String packageName, long flags)
    throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        return pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(flags));
    } else {
        return getPackageInfoLegacy(pm, packageName, (int) flags);
    }
}
```

> Cannot resolve symbol 'TIRAMISU'

> Cannot resolve symbol 'PackageInfoFlags'

The version of compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in `build.gradle` both is `33`

```
android {
namespace "com.getcapacitor.android"
compileSdkVersion project.hasProperty('compileSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion : 33
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion project.hasProperty('minSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion : 22
    targetSdkVersion project.hasProperty('targetSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion : 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
...}
```

I did update also my Android Studio to the latest version and grandle to `8.0.2`.

Does anyone know the problem or can help me solve it?

Btw. actually I can build the project, but i still see this error in Android Studio.

Here also the version of Java `17.x.x`:
[image]

Comment: have you find solution to it ?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to change the `targetSDK` and `compileSDK` to 33. Of course you also need to have Android SDK 33 (TIRAMISU) installed

[image]